# how to convert the data coming from snapshot into List to fit in this column?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

my this code is showing me error that querysnapshot is not a subtype of a list. can you edit my code and tell me how to make this error free.

```
buildProfilePosts() {
    if (_isLoading) {
      return Center(
        child: Text(
          "Loading...",
          style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "QuickSand"),
        ),
      );
    }
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: postsRef.document(widget.profileId).collection('userPosts').orderBy('timestamp', descending: true).snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return Column(
          children: snapshot.data,
        );
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: what  snapshot.data returning?

Comment: I have created one collection of posts in that I have document with id as profileId in that I have collection as userPosts, in that I have documents with id of different postId, each document consists of a post

Comment: I want to have that list of posts

Comment: have you checked my answer?

Comment: @PeterHaddad I have checked your answer, It just shows me circularprogressindicator all the time nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`children` is a property inside the widget `Column`, it takes a list of widgets. You should do the following:

```
child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          StreamBuilder(
            stream: postsRef.document(widget.profileId).collection('userPosts').orderBy('timestamp', descending: true).snapshots(),,
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                return ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        title:
                            Text(snapshot.data.documents[index].data["name"]),
                      );
                    });
              } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
                return Text("No data");
              }
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
          ]),
```

Assuming you have a `name` field in your document.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ...List.generate(
              snapshot.data.length,
                  (index) {
                return Container(
                  child: Text(snapshot.data[index].yourobject),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: The getter 'length' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try importing the library that defines 'length', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'length'.

Comment: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try defining the operator '[]'.